# Google charts. How to use chart.draw(data, options) with data coming from a text or csv file?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a simple html file that I am using to display a bar chart using google charts. I would like to get the data array from the contents of a text file.

Seems like I should be able to define:
var  contents =  *** some way to read contents of text file ***
and then:
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(contents)

Can this be done?

Simplified version of how it is now, working great, WITHOUT the text file:

```
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    //**   ideally, the data that follows would be in a text or csv file *//
    [
      ['UNITS PRODUCED', 'Shipped', 'Invoiced', 'Produced'  ],
      ['PLANT#1', 1000,  400,  200  ],
      ['PLANT#2', 1170,  460,  250  ],
    ]
    //**  End contents derived from text or csv file *//
    );

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Current Week Performance',
        subtitle: 'Through mm/dd/YYYY',
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, if the text data is the CSV format, you can convert it to an array for `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array)` using a script. If the text data is not the CSV format, it is required to parse it and convert to an array. By the way, can I ask you about `some way` of `some way to read contents of text file`? If you have not been able to read the text data from the file yet, can I ask you where the text file is?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937069/5090771)...