# Dinamically populate google chart just using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, webbrowser-control

I'm using Google Charts API inside my C# project (using the WebBrowser from CefSharp), and it works with the data hard coded to it, but I'm running into a problem whenever I try to dinamically populate it using data.addRows(). I need to have something simple, like a external csv/json, so it's possible to run inside C# (WebBrowser is really limited and sometimes buggy), but every solution tells me to do that via php server or something more "complex" like that. So, is there a way to populate that chart just using JavaScript and an external file (or something different but viable)?

Thats the code, if useful:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
        data.addRows([['Alice', 'Mike', ''],['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],['Carol', 'Bob', '']]);

        // Create the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
        chart.draw(data, {'allowHtml':true});
      }
   </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obs: CefSharp WebBrowser just calls this code above as a normal HTML file and runs it inside the C# application.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the code? Does nothing get rendered to the `chart_div`?

Comment: This code works. I just want to populate data.addrows() from an external file  (csv, json, even txt)

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937069/5090771) for using CSV...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar, but I've been using the `arrayToDataTable()` method of the google charts API, but I'm sure this can be done similarly. You will need to lean on C# though. I wanted to be thorough so this is a big one. More than happy to clarify because I'm sure that at least some of this will be poorly worded/confusing.

**TLDR**

1. Create a Class to hold your data points and a way to represent them as a list.
2. In Your Controller class, Create a method that returns a list containing your data points represented as lists. Turn that List of lists into JSON and Post it to a URL endpoint
3. Read your json data from that endpoint using ajax in the cshtml
4. Put the read json into your AddRows method.
5. Party

This will touch on : the .cshtml, the Home Controller, and Wherever you are pulling your data.

1. Wherever you are pulling your Data

My case is a bit complicated. But basically I have a method that just returns a list of type `object` that holds these objects, represented as lists. (eg. `[<Timestamp>,<Temperature>,<Humidity>]`)

```
public class WeatherEntry
{
       public string Timestamp { get; set; } 
       public double TEMPERATURE { get; set; } 
       public double Humidity { get; set; } 
... Other stuff ...
}
```

If you can generate a list of data points, represented as lists on the c# side, you are in business.

2. The Controller class

Assuming you are using ASP.net MVC, you'll have a backing controller class that holds your Controlling C#

Once you have a list **of type object** containing your data points **represented as lists**, you can make it into JSON pretty easily using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)'s `JSonConvert.SerializeObject()` Method as such:

```
          public ActionResult GetChartData_All_Week()
          {
              var dataPointsList = this.myDataSource.GetMyDataPointList();
              var convertedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPointsList, new JsonSerializerSettings()
              {
                  //Not Needed, I just like to throw out any values that are null.
                  NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
              }); 

              return Content(convertedJson);
```

**IMPORTANT** We'll be using ajax in the next step, so we need the magical `[Route]` Attribute above this action result method as such:

```
Route("Index/Path/To/Post/To")]
public ActionResult GetChartData_All_Week()
```

All the hard stuff is done now. If you launch your App and visit the route you defined above (For me it is `/Index/Charts/All/Week`) You should see your JSON data there similar to this:

```
[["07/04/2020",25.5,44.0],["07/05/2020",25.600000381469727,45.0],["07/06/2020",25.5,44.0],...["07/08/2020",25.5,43.0]]
```

If You don't then this next part isn't going to work out. **Always remember that it is a List of Lists we will need!**

3. The .cshtml, AJAX, and jQuery magic
   Most of your chart is already there. If It's working with the sample data as you posted, this will be *super ez*. inside your `drawChart()` method, you'll add the following before the `data.AddRows()` call.

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url:'Index/Path/To/Post/To',
                dataType:"json",
                async:false,
                type:"GET"
                }).responseText;
var asJson = JSON.parse(jsonData);
data.AddRows(asJson);
```

And now you should have it! The page and datasource will require a refresh to chart any *new* data that is added, but this should give you a dynamically sized list of points. The hardest part that I had was formatting my data as a List of Lists. I would recommend adding a `CS List<object> ToList()` method to whatever your equivalent to my `Weather_Entry` class is to put all of the important Data points into a list *in order**. That makes it nice and easy to do something like:

```
public List<object> GetMyDataPointList(){
     var myDataPointList = new List<MyDataPointType>();
     myDataPointList = this.GetMyListOfDataPoints();
     List<object> turnMeIntoJSON = new List<object>();
     myDataPointList.ForEach(dp => turnMeIntoJSON.Add(dp.ToList));
    return turnMeIntoJSON;
}
```

Best of Luck!

Comment: Nice detailed answer. The only thing I would add for clarification is that the ajax call is using jQuery in your example.

Comment: @CodyLohse, Thanks! I'm a total noob when it comes to web stuff, I was completely unaware that I was using jQuery (though I have heard of it). Updating the post!